# What are the risks LSD microdosing?

Tags: recreational-drugs, productivity

I have recently seen several news articles about LSD microdosing: [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/12019140/Silicon-Valley-professionals-are-taking-LSD-at-work-to-increase-productivity.html), [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/robertglatter/2015/11/27/lsd-microdosing-the-new-job-enhancer-in-silicon-valley-and-beyond/), [TechInsider](http://www.techinsider.io/lsd-microdosing-is-the-new-productivity-craze-2015-11), etc.

Definition from [Rolling Stones](http://www.rollingstone.com/culture/features/how-lsd-microdosing-became-the-hot-new-business-trip-20151120):

> A microdose is about a tenth of the normal dose – around 10 micrograms of LSD, or 0.2-0.5 grams of mushrooms.

What short-term and long-term risks LSD microdosing have been shown in scientific studies, if any?

Answer (score 4):

### Here are the sources you can use:

The main issue is that due to government controls on substances like LSD, *very little* research ends up being conducted with/about them due to the difficulties and regulations involved. So information about substances like LSD comes from three main sources:

1. The few peer-reviewed academic/pharmaceutical studies which make it past Institutional Review and government regulations to be published in a journal
2. Content written by "experts," but *not* peer-reviewed and *not* processed by an Institutional Review Board and *not* published in a journal
3. Community knowledge and user reports

On the first count, here's [a link to a literature review article from 1984.](https://wiki.dmt-nexus.me/w/images/5/5c/psychedelic_adverse_effects.pdf)

On the second count, you can look into the work of Aldous Huxley, George Greer, Ann Shulgin, Myron Stolaroff, Athanasios Kafkalides, and Stanislav Grof.

On the third count, you can check out community forums at reddit, erowid, and bluelight.

### Here's what they generally say:

You cannot take a toxic dose of LSD, though large doses could put you in a state in which you're life is in danger (e.g. you might accidentally walk off a cliff).

Most if not all reported effects of LSD (after the substance's primary effects have waned) are psychological, ranging from the mundane (e.g. self-discovery, introspection) to the phenomenal (e.g. PTSD, complete personality change).

Some people report experiencing "flashbacks," where they unexpectedly feel like their state of consciousness shifts momentarily back into a psychedelic state. While such reports are popular, they seem relatively rare and unlikely.

Ultimately, not enough users provide a large enough amount of reliable, objective data to say anything definite about long-term effects.

Answer (score 2):

The 2022-02-10 study {1} didn't find any risks for LSD microdosing:

> We conclude that within the context of a controlled setting and a limited number of administrations, **repeated low doses of LSD are safe**, but produce negligible changes in mood or cognition in healthy volunteers.

---

References:

- {1} de Wit, H, Molla, HM, Bershad, A, Bremmer, M, Lee, R. Repeated low doses of LSD in healthy adults: A placebo-controlled, dose–response study. *Addiction Biology*. 2022; 27 (2):e13143. doi:[10.1111/adb.13143](https://doi.org/10.1111/adb.13143)